# How should we treat greetings and salutations?

Tags: discussion

This question is based on: *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/192661)*

Here are examples at this site:

- https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/11938/4644
- https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/11962/4644
- https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/1785/4644

How do you think we should treat them?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Answer (score 4):

I personally frown down upon them, but I don't always directly remove them. Especially if its a one-off case, I don't think its worth the effort (albeit very small).

In the first case I think we should simply point out to GetFitChimp that we'd prefer it if he left it out of his answers in the future.

In the second case, I believe that user simply copied GetFitChimp, since I never see him do it on SO (yes I checked, sue me).

In the last case we had an inexperienced user, who thought it was polite to add it, which is probably the reason people use it in the first place.

So what to do? Leave a comment pointing it out that they can leave it off, since its unnecessary. While editing it out, you can leave a comment saying the same thing, which is probably enough in the case of a drive by user.

Comment: I think when I've run across them I've just removed them without leaving a message about it. Inexperienced people or one-offs won't be back to get the message, as people grow more accustomed to the site, they catch on pretty quick that we don't do signatures and taglines here.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary, though polite and well-intentioned, as the site's purpose is for questions and answers. If it's a new user, I include it with the comment, meta posts, or chat where appropriate and contextual. If it's not a core part of the answer, I leave it out. If other people come here to read and search for information, those kinds of cruft detract from the answer. There are other (and better) outlets for being social and welcoming and personal.

Answer (score 2):

I edit it out if I'm editing the post for other reasons.

I try not to burden new users with anything but the absolute bare minimum of the weirdo rules and etiquette on SE, which means I don't mention it to someone until they've been around a little while.

Answer (score 0):

As the others say, I never edit simply to just remove this clutter, but I take it as an invitation to look closer and check for other errors.

The first two examples look pretty good from judging by a quick glance.

In the third example I'd add line breaks and paragraphs as I think the readability is pretty low. If you look at the markdown of the text you can see that at least one line break was intended by the user but it got scrapped away by the engine.

Update:
I now will go on editing answers of users that use those unnecessary formalism on multiple occasions.

Comment: That particular answer smells like Spam, double link, buzzword-dropping, at least fishy …

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on a different meta site, I believe the answer there is valid here as well: https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1159/30949